# Passing dynamic parameter to a JavaScript function using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am having issues passing a dynamic parameter to a JavaScript function using innerHTML.

Included below is the current code that I am using:

```
var name = "test";

frm.innerHtml = '<button name="close" id="close" title="Cancel" type="button"
     onclick="closeTab('+name+');">Return</button>';
```

When I debug the code of the `closeTab()` function, the parameter specified by the `name` variable is `null`.

I believe there is a problem with the declaration of the value while modifying the innerHTML property.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do u mean i simply use the variable name without quotes? Thanks

Comment: you used the value of name as a variable, add quotations.

Comment: You should use DOM like `document.createElement` and others instead of setting `innerHtml` because it's cleaner

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I simply used onclick="closeTab(name);"> in innerHTML and it worked. I guess that worked coz name is global variable.

Comment: The usage of name in this context passes it to the closeTab() function as a variable, not a string.  Ideally, function execution in this context should receive the string, not a global variable.

Answer (score 6):

Your dynamic declaration is passing the parameter as a variable, instead of the value of the parameter.  In order to correct this issue, you must pass the value as a string, instead of a variable, which is accomplished by encasing and escaping the variable in single quotes as demonstrated below:

```
var name = "test";

frm.innerHtml = '<button name="close"  id="close"  title="Cancel" type="button"
      onclick="closeTab(\''+name+'\');">Return</button>';
```

Comment: I used double quotes which not worked, you showed that single is needed \' ... gj, you helped me

Answer (score 5):

Your resulting code is:

```
<button ... onclick="closeTab(test);">Return</button>
```

Can you see what's wrong? `test` is being treated as a variable, when you actually intended it to be a string.

I like to use `JSON.stringify` to make a variable parseable (kind of like [`var_export`](http://php.net/var-export) in PHP), but in this case you also need to escape quotes. So:

```
JSON.stringify(test).replace(/"/g,"&quot;")
```

Use that in your button instead of just `test`.

Comment: That only works because `name` is a global variable, but as soon as you do anything more complicated it will be "inexplicably" broken.

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM:

```
var name="test";
var el = document.createElement("button");
el.name = "close";
el.id = "close";
el.title = "Cancel";
el.type = "button";
el.onclick = function() {  // an inline function that will be executed when el is clicked
    closeTab(name);        // `name` here contains `"test"`
};
frm.appendChild(el);
```

I really don't encourage overusing `innerHTML` as it is messy, and can sometime be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html is -

```
<form id='frm'>

</form>
```

Your JS should be -

```
var name = "test";
var innerHtml = "<button name='close' id='close' title='Cancel'   type='button'>Return</button>";
$("#frm").html(innerHtml);
$("#close").attr("onclick","javascript:closeTab('"+name+"');");
```

Check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/arindam006/avgHz/1/

This is the cleanest way to achieve this, though innerHtml is not a proper way to do it as everyone suggested above.